# Is there an efficient way to select certain characters from a string?

Tags: python, string

I have the following sequences, as you might guess I only want the characters A,C,G,T,- and ignore the rest. Length of the input file may change and there may be a line such as sequence747 etc.

`"sequence1 ATAC---CTAATTGGAGATGATCAAATTTATAAT"`

`"sequence2 TTAT---CTAATTGGCGACGATCAAATTTATAAT"`

`"sequence3 ATAT---CTAATTGGTGATGATCAAATTTATAAT"`

`"sequence4 ATCA---TTAATTGGAGATGATCAATCCTAATGA"`

`"sequence5 CTGTACTTTTATTGGTGATAGTCAAATCTATAAT"`

So far I have tried this and it works as I wanted:

```
aligned_lines = []
for line in lines:
    temp_str = ""
    for element in line:
        if element == 'A' or element == 'C' or element == 'G' or element == 'T' or element == '-':
            temp_str += element
    aligned_lines.append(temp_str)
```

But is there any more efficient way to do it with less code? Any built in python tool to construct new string from another string with certain characters in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more efficient way would be to [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) (using regular expression) the string on unwanted chunks and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the remainders back together:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r"[^ACGT-]+")

for line in lines:
    aligned_lines.append(''.join(pat.split(line)))
    # even better, as suggested: pat.sub('', s)
```

Some explanation on the regex:

```
"[^XYZ]"    # anything that is NOT X or Y or Z
"X+"        # one or more X
"[^ACGT]+"  # one or more of anything not A, C, G, or T
```

**Some more notes:**
What makes your approach particularly inefficient is the incremental construction of a string. As strings are immutable, `temp_str += element` must create a new `str` object which is an expensive operation (`~len(temp_str)`). This makes the entire process quadratic. You would already have a linear approach if you collected your `elements` in a `list` and joined that list into a `str` in the end.
And, of course, your big `if`-condition can be shortened dramatically, e.g. `if element in "ACGT":`. Hence, your approach in an improved version would go along the following lines:

```
for line in lines:
    aligned_lines.append(''.join(e for e in line if e in "ACGT"))
```

This, in turn, could be fancified:

```
for line in lines:
    aligned_lines.append(''.join(filter("ACGT".__contains__, line)))
```

Comment: Maybe one approach could also be replacing the characters that are not in wanted set, if we are using regular expressions. For instance:

`s = re.sub(r'[^ACGT-]', '', s)`

Answer (score 0):

As you'd like to get only the second half of each line, I think a simple `str.split()` will do it for you:

```
lines=[
"sequence1 ATAC---CTAATTGGAGATGATCAAATTTATAAT",
"sequence2 TTAT---CTAATTGGCGACGATCAAATTTATAAT",
"sequence3 ATAT---CTAATTGGTGATGATCAAATTTATAAT",
"sequence4 ATCA---TTAATTGGAGATGATCAATCCTAATGA",
"sequence5 CTGTACTTTTATTGGTGATAGTCAAATCTATAAT"]

for line in lines:
    ignore,keep = line.split()
    # The result will be in the keep variable
```